# Visual Studio 2010 won't save TFS as current source control plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm configuring VS.Net 2010 on a new Win7 PC to connect to a Team Foundation Server repository. After selecting Team Foundation Server as the current source control plugin under Tools -> Options, VS.Net keeps switching back to "None".

If I choose TFS, click Ok, and immediately open a solution that uses TFS, VS.Net says it can't contact source control and asks if I want to temporarily work unbound. The odd thing is that every few tries everything works, and I can work connected to TFS.

If I choose TFS, click OK, and immediately go back into Tools->Options, 2 out of 3 times "None" will be selected as the source control provider.

Also tried running VS.Net with and without admin privileges, with same results.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was caused by legacy source control bindings still present in the .csproj and .sln files, left in place after the project was imported from VSS to TFS. I didn't have VSS installed on my system, which is why I got this error (the VSS provider couldn't be found). To resolve, you should unbind the project from the legacy source provider when prompted, and then rebind to TFS using File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control.

This link was very helpful...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nagendra/archive/2005/09/30/475633.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to start VS2010 in safe mode

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

Run the above command in a command prompt. That should start VS2010 without any plugin enabled. Then go into Tools > Options and choose your Source Control (eg: TFS or any other) and click OK. That should solve the hassle.